# If $K^{\times}/R^{\times}$ is a free abelian group, then must $R$ be a UFD?

Tags: integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

Given an integral domain $R$, let $K$ be the field of fractions of $R$. Then, it is easily seen that if $R$ is a unique factorization domain, then the quotient group $K^{\times}/R^{\times}$ is a free abelian group.

Conversely, if $K^{\times}/R^{\times}$ is a free abelian group, then must $R$ be a UFD?

Special cases:

- If $K^{\times}/R^{\times}$ is the trivial group, then that means that $R$ is already a field. Fields are trivially UFDs.
- If $K^{\times}/R^{\times}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, then let $\frac{a}{b}R^{\times}$ be either of the two generators of that infinite cyclic group. Then, one would be done if one could show that either $a \mid b$ (so $\frac{b}{a} \in R$) or $b \mid a$ (so $\frac{a}{b} \in R$), and then $R$ would be a discrete valuation ring with uniformizer $\frac{b}{a}$ or $\frac{a}{b}$, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}]$ is a PID thus $$\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-7}]^*/\Bbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}]^\times=\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-7}]^*/\Bbb{Z}[7\sqrt{-7}]^\times$$ is a free abelian group,

but $\Bbb{Z}[7\sqrt{-7}]$ is not a UFD: $7^3 = -(7\sqrt{-7})^2$

Comment: The crucial thing here, I suppose, is that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-7}\,]$ is not integrally closed. If I recalll, a UFD has to be entire, so I guess that $\Bbb Z[2i]$ would do as well.

Comment: You mean $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$, for $2i$ you'll get that $i$ is torsion in $K^*/R^*$

Comment: I was about to delete that comment, for various reasons. With your response up, I guess I’m condemned to have it remain. Thanks for the correction.